# Xcode AppleScript Application execute only

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

I build an Application in Xcode using AppleScript.
I know from the AppleScript-Editor that i can mark my Scripts as **"only execute"**, so that they can't be edited again.

Now the Question is, can i do so also in Xcode with that Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option is in the build settings. Search for "execute".

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm so blind with all that settings…